# Difference between a[1] and a[1:1] in lists

Tags: python, list, slice

If we have a list `a = [1,2,3,4]`
and list `b = [5,6,7]`

why is `a[1]` interpreted differently than `a[1:1]` and what exactly is the difference?

If I want to add all of list `b` to list `a` at index `1`, so that the list `a` becomes `[1,5,6,7,2,3,4]` why do I have to run `a[1:1] = b` instead of `a[1] = b`?

how exactly is `a[1:1]` interpreted?

Comment: The difference is replacing a single element of list `a` with list `b` (making it nested) as opposed to replacing an (empty) sublist of `a` with `b`.

Comment: I think this is a timely question. The behaviour is unexpected imo and doesn't feel very pythonic, but afaik it is the simplest way to insert (and unpack) a list into another list. The explanations below are as good as they will get, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

`a[1:1]` means an empty slice spanning from before index `1`, and until before index `1`. It does not include `1`, as that would be `a[1:2]`.

When you replace that empty slice, you basically insert the new list in that position.

If you do `a[1]` you replace the item at position `1` with the list.

Some examples:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,4,4,4]
>>> a[1] = b
>>> a
[1, [4, 4, 4, 4], 3]    # [4, 4, 4, 4] is a sublist
>>> a[1]
[4, 4, 4, 4]
>>> len(a)
3  # List contains only 3 items - `1`, the sublist, and `3`.
>>> a = [1,2,3] # Reset back
>>> a[1:1] = b
>>> a
[1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3]
>>> len(a)
7  # List contains 7 integers
```

Answer (score 0):

`a[1]` is for get single value from list by index in square brackets (0 is first value)
and `a[1:1]` is for get subset of list, not only one value. ([start:end]), but in this case get empty list, because start and end it's same